# Get json data from ajax,process it,return answer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have some troubles with transfer json data.

I have some dynamic page. I collect data to json object "Filters".

```
var Filters = { daterange: $('#daterange').val(), shop: val_shop, pr: val_pr, plan: val_plan, TabsList: TabsList }

$.ajax({
    url: "/Reports/Report_2",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(
        Filters
    )
});
```

I try get it with JObject.

```
public IActionResult Report_2() //main Action 
    {
        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Report_2([FromBody]JObject jsonResult)//catch json object
    {
        //do something
        return View(_context.MyDatabase.Result);//return data from database for table(Razor Page)
    }
```

I get Error 415. =(

If I try don't overload Report_2 Action().

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Reports/Report_2_Filter",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(
        Filters
    )
});
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<JObject> Report_2_Filter([FromBody]JObject jsonResult)
    {

        return jsonResult;
    }
```

I don't know how return result on **Report_2** page. I need result on Report_2 Action becouse I must fill table on Report_2 page. I'm  newbee in web, so I will be greateful for any help.

Comment: You probably get more than just a 415 - what's the content of the reply?

Comment: Could you share the complete code of view and javascript.I failed to reproduce your issue based on the provided code ,it worked well. If you want to fill the table on Report_2 page , you could use the [Partial view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to contains that table ,then render the partial view in the success function of ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
I create class which stores variables:

```
public class FilterModel
{
    public string var1{ get; set; }
    public string var2{ get; set; }
    public string var3{ get; set; }
    public string var4{ get; set; }
    public List<string> var5{ get; set; }
}
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Report_2(FilterModel filter)
    {
        FilterLogic filterLogic = new FilterLogic(_context);
        var result = filterLogic.GetResult(filter);
        return View();  
    }
```

In JS I use jQuery function $.post

```
 $.post("/Reports/Report_2", { var1: $('#var1').val(), var2: var2, var3: var3, var4: var4, var5: var5});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a function to be executed on success. Try to add the following to your ajax request:

```
success: function(data){
  // Do something here
}
```

Have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) to see the ajax events.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need write ("");

```
var Filters = { "daterange": $('#daterange').val(), "shop": val_shop, "pr": val_pr, "plan": val_plan, "TabsList": TabsList }
```

Comment: Don't think that is a problem. Main problem - If I add JObject in Action parameter I get error 415.